# Loading a partial view dynamically and loading index from controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am at a loss on how to do this. I've tried every search I can think of.  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

The customer wanted to be able to load a partial view dynamically from a wysiwyg editor.  So, I made a method in the controller that searches for a special tag that gets the name of the partial view. Got that to work fine.  Now the customer wants to load and post data to/from the partial view.

I was able to get it loaded by doing this -   finalhtml += PartialView("~/Views/Global/Partials/" + commandContents + ".cshtml").RenderPartialViewToString();

If I name the controller the exact name of the partial view plus controller ie: SamplePartialController, I can get the view post back to the controller, BUT I can't figure out how to load an initial index method on the partial no matter what I try.

It would be nice if I could define the initial index method and controller name programmatically, just not seeing a way.

I am fairly new to mvc, been doing asp.net for over a decade, and this may be very obvious, but I'm just not finding a way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand clearly the issue. I also had a lot of troubles working with partial views (to post data, to load them back if something wrong happened in the post action...).

It seems like you want to fill your partial view if some parameters are here when loading the index.

In the Controller.Index (or where you get your parameters) you can assign some ViewModel values, or use the ViewBag/ViewData.

In the index view, you can call where you need the RenderPartialAsync() based on your parameters setted previously

```
this.ViewData["error"] = Model.Error;
this.ViewData["partialGuid"] = Guid.NewGuid();
this.ViewData["foo"] = bar;

await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialViewName", Model.PartialViewModel, this.ViewData);
```

And use your partial view the same way you do from an ajax call.

If you need to post data from your partial view, I struggled a lot with some things:

1. A FormContext is required in the partial view

```
@if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null)
{
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
```

2. If you allow to push multiple times your partial view and post them, making a custom collectionId helps a lot when in the controller post action

```
@{
    var collectionId = $"PartialItems[{this.ViewData["partialGuid"]}].{{0}}";
}

// then later...

<input class="form-control"
        data-val="true"
        data-val-required="@(string.Format(ApplicationResources.Error_Required, ApplicationResources.FieldFirstName))"
        id="@(string.Format(collectionId, "FirstName"))"
        name="@(string.Format(collectionId, "FirstName"))"
        type="text"
        value="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.FirstName) ? string.Empty : Model.FirstName)" />
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger"
        data-valmsg-for="@(string.Format(collectionId, "FirstName"))"
        data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

// And in your Index ViewModel, something like that to get the collection in the controller post action

public IDictionary<string, PartialViewModel> PartialItems { get; set; }
```

3. If you call the new partial view with Ajax, after the first render of the view, reset the jquery validator if needed

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function (res) {

        // do your stuff
        $('#parentId').prepend(res);

        // reinit the validation
        $("form").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    }
});
```

It is almost everything I can think of that bugged me when dealing the first time with all this partial view things. Hope something here can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the VERY detailed answer. I will go through it when I get back to my station and let you know. To boil it down Im basically looking for a pageload event like in Asp.net user controls.